# response sent twice even after returning and using async await

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to send just one response back to the client if the validation has failed, but the code below that line gets executed and I get the error "cannot set headers after sent". why am I getting this error when I am using async/await?

```
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        let toCreate = {}
        mapUsers(toCreate, req.body)
        await validateUser(toCreate, res)
        toCreate.password = await bcrypt.hashPassword(toCreate.password)
        let newUser = await User.create({...toCreate})
        res.status(200).json({
            msg: 'user created', newUser
        })
})
```

validate user function:

```
module.exports = async (user, res) => {
        if(!user.name) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name is required'})
        if(user.name.length < 5) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name must have more than 5 characters'})
        }
}
```

Comment: is it an issue with the browser? sent extra OPTION request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any async code in the validate function so using `await` make no sence.

There's many ways to fix your code. One could be:

```
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    let toCreate = {}
    mapUsers(toCreate, req.body)

    // no need to use await since the function is synchronous
    let err = validateUser(toCreate, res)
    if (err)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: err })

    toCreate.password = await bcrypt.hashPassword(toCreate.password)
    let newUser = await User.create({...toCreate})
    res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'user created', newUser
    })
})
```

and the validate function

```
module.exports = (user) => {
    if(!user.name)
        return 'name is required';
    if(user.name.length < 5)
        return 'name must have more than 5 characters';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the username is invalid, `validateUser` function will send a response. The creation of a user will happen anyways, since you are not stopping execution even if the user is invalid.

You could return `true` or false from `validateUser` and depending on that build up your response. Also `validateUser` has no `async` parts in it. So remove the async for simplicity and not needing to await it anymore:

##### Register

```js
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
        let toCreate = {}
        mapUsers(toCreate, req.body)
        if(validateUser(toCreate, res) === false) {
            return
        }
        toCreate.password = await bcrypt.hashPassword(toCreate.password)
        let newUser = await User.create({...toCreate})
        res.status(200).json({
            msg: 'user created', newUser
        })
})
```

##### `validateUser`

```js
module.exports = (user, res) => {
        if(!user.name) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name is required'})
            return false
         }
        if(user.name.length < 5) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name must have more than 5 characters'})
            return false
        }
        return true
}
```

An more clean solution to the problem could be a separate handler for validating usernames before creation. You could add following handler for username validation (and more) in the chain before your register hook.

```js
   exports.validateUser = (req, res, next) => {
      // only perform the check on the register location. 
      // Maybe add a better check.. This is just for showing the idea
      if(req.url.indexOf('/register') > -1) {
          let toCreate = {}
          mapUsers(toCreate , req.body)
    
          
          // store the mapped users in the request for accessing it later!
          req.auth = req.auth || {} 
          req.auth.mappedUsers = toCreate
          
          if(!user.name) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name is required'})
            // return for not calling next! .
            return
         }
        if(user.name.length < 5) {
            res.status(400).json({ msg: 'name must have more than 5 characters'})
            // return for not calling next! .
            return
        }
      }
      
      // if it's not register location OR no checks failed, call the next handler!
      next()
   }
```

The final handler for creating a user would only be called when
the username is valid! The registerHandler does also not need to be `async`.
There is no `async` function in it called so keep it simple! .
The new register handler:

```
exports.register = req, res, next) => {
        // the validateUser handler was called before and already 
        // mapped the user. If the code gets in here, the username is 
        // valid. 
        let toCreate = req.mappedUsers
        toCreate.password = await bcrypt.hashPassword(toCreate.password)
        let newUser = await User.create({...toCreate})
        res.status(200).json({
            msg: 'user created', newUser
        })
}
```